# How can I check Emojis simultaneously in discord.py re-write?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I wanted to create a custom help command which uses reactions to show the classes commands. During my tests I noticed that in order to get the 2nd reaction and 2nd message, etc., to  work, I first need to trigger the 1st reaction and the 1st message. However, then it would make no sense to create a help command in that way.

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

I want the users to choose what kind of help command/category they want to see, not force them to see them all as they are not always looking for everything.

**What has to be done?**

I would say the way to get it working is to tell the bot that the 1st emoji is for the 1st embed, which I defined, the 2nd for the 2nd embed, the 3rd for the 3rd, etc. It shall not matter which emoji is used first.

**My code so far:**

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def test1(self, ctx):
        embed = Embed(title=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Hilfe', description='**Hinweis:**\n'
        '`[]`, wenn es für den Command notwendig ist!\n'
        '`{}`, wenn zwischen ID, Name oder Name#1234 entschieden werden kann\n'
        '`()`, wenn es nicht benötigt wird, aber genutzt werden kann.\n'
        'Reagiere auf die Emotes, um die gewünschte Hilfe anzuzeigen!',
                              colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- Allgemeine Commands', value='Commands, die jeder Nutzen kann.', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- Commands für die Moderation', value='Commands, die Moderatoren unterstützen.',
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- Commands für Administratoren',
                        value='Nur Administratoren können diese Commands nutzen.', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- Music Commands', value='Abfahrt!', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- andere Commands', value='Commands, die keiner Kategorie wirklich angehören.',
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=' │- Ownercommands', value=f'Commands, die nur {botowner} nutzen können.', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='❤ │- Commands, die uns bewerben', value='Commands mit Eigenwerbung', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**Hinweis**',
                        value='Du hast 2 Minuten Zeit zu reagieren. Danach verschwinden die Symbole.', inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://media4.giphy.com/media/Pn6FasMtzbU0C5licS/giphy.gif')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('❤')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        embed2 = Embed(title=' │- Allgemeine Commands',
                               description='Diese Commands kann in der Regeln jeder nutzen!',
                               colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed2.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}help`', value='Zeigt das Auswahlfenster der Commands an!', inline=True)
        embed2.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}stats`', value='Zeigt Stats zum Bot an!', inline=True)
        embed2.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}ping`', value='Zeigt den Ping an!', inline=True)
        embed2.set_thumbnail(url='https://media4.giphy.com/media/VI2UC13hwWin1MIfmi/giphy.gif')
        embed2.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)

        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed2)

        def check2(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        embed3 = Embed(title=' │- Commands für die Moderation',
                               description='Diese Commands unterstützen die Moderation.',
                               colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed3.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}kick' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Kickt Nutzer.', inline=True)
        embed3.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}ban' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Bannt Nutzer permanent.', inline=True)
        embed3.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}unban' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Entbannt Nutzer.'),
        embed3.set_thumbnail(url='https://i.imgur.com/O3DHIA5.gif')
        embed3.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
        try:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check2)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed3)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.clear_reactions()
            return
```

I tried to check the emojis simultaneously by putting them all at the top, but then it just sends the first embed when I react to anything so I've kept it like that until I will find a solution. During my test(s) no errors occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@commands.command()
async def test1(self, ctx):

    embed = Embed(title=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Hilfe', description='**Hinweis:**\n'
     '`[]`, wenn es für den Command notwendig ist!\n'
     '`{}`, wenn zwischen ID, Name oder Name#1234 entschieden werden kann\n'
     '`()`, wenn es nicht benötigt wird, aber genutzt werden kann.\n'
     'Reagiere auf die Emotes, um die gewünschte Hilfe anzuzeigen!', colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- Allgemeine Commands', value='Commands, die jeder Nutzen kann.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- Commands für die Moderation', value='Commands, die Moderatoren unterstützen.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- Commands für Administratoren', value='Nur Administratoren können diese Commands nutzen.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- Music Commands', value='Abfahrt!', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- andere Commands', value='Commands, die keiner Kategorie wirklich angehören.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=' │- Ownercommands', value=f'Commands, die nur {botowner} nutzen können.', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='❤ │- Commands, die uns bewerben', value='Commands mit Eigenwerbung', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='**Hinweis**', value='Du hast 2 Minuten Zeit zu reagieren. Danach verschwinden die Symbole.', inline=False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://media4.giphy.com/media/Pn6FasMtzbU0C5licS/giphy.gif')
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('❤')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and (str(reaction.emoji) == '' or str(reaction.emoji) == '')
  
    try:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check)
        
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            embed = Embed(title=' │- Allgemeine Commands', description='Diese Commands kann in der Regeln jeder nutzen!', colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}help`', value='Zeigt das Auswahlfenster der Commands an!', inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}stats`', value='Zeigt Stats zum Bot an!', inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}ping`', value='Zeigt den Ping an!', inline=True)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://media4.giphy.com/media/VI2UC13hwWin1MIfmi/giphy.gif')
            embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            embed = Embed(title=' │- Commands für die Moderation', description='Diese Commands unterstützen die Moderation.',
                       colour=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}kick' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Kickt Nutzer.', inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}ban' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Bannt Nutzer permanent.', inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name=f'`{prefix}unban' + '[{Nutzer}]`', value='Entbannt Nutzer.', 
            embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://i.imgur.com/O3DHIA5.gif')
            embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed3)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await msg.clear_reactions()
        return
```

How about something like this? Basically you're check just makes sure they use any of the valid emojis and then once it gets the response it checks what emoji was selected and creates an embed based on that.

Comment: Thank you! With your help I was able to get a solution.